# Reaction Kinetics and Stoichiometry -- Mass conservation

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics

This question has been bothering me for some time, and I can't seem to find a good answer online.

Say I have four chemical species $\ce{A}$, $\ce{B}$, $\ce{C}$, $\ce{D}$, and these four react in the following ways:

\begin{align}\ce{
A + A &-> B\\
A + B &-> C\\
A + C &-> D\\
A + D &-> B + C\\
}\end{align}

The kinetic reaction equations for these four species should be:
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}[\ce{A}]}{\mathrm{d}t} &= -k_1[\ce{A}]^2-k_2[\ce{A}][\ce{B}]-k_3[\ce{A}][\ce{C}]-k_4[\ce{A}][\ce{D}]\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}[\ce{B}]}{\mathrm{d}t} &= +k_1[\ce{A}]^2  -k_2[\ce{A}][\ce{B}] +k_4[\ce{A}][\ce{D}]\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}[\ce{C}]}{\mathrm{d}t} &= +k_2[\ce{A}][\ce{B}] -k_3[\ce{A}][\ce{C}] +k_4[\ce{A}][\ce{D}]\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}[\ce{D}]}{\mathrm{d}t} &= +k_3[\ce{A}][\ce{C}] -k_4[\ce{A}][\ce{D}]\\
\end{align}

where $k_i$ is the Arrhenius coefficient for that reaction.

In my mind, the stoichiometry does not seem to add up right. It seems that when the system undergoes $\ce{A + A -> B}$, the concentration of $\ce{A}$ should decrease by twice as much as a reaction like $\ce{A + B -> C}$. Similarly, the products of $\ce{A + D}$ should be split evenly between $\ce{B}$ and $\ce{C}$.

Therefore, stoichiometrically, I want to write: 
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}[\ce{A}]}{\mathrm{d}t} &= -2k_1[\ce{A}]^2-k_2[\ce{A}][\ce{B}]-k_3[\ce{A}][\ce{C}]-k_4[\ce{A}][\ce{D}]\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}[\ce{B}]}{\mathrm{d}t} &= +k_1[\ce{A}]^2  -k_2[\ce{A}][\ce{B}] +\tfrac{1}{2}k_4[\ce{A}][\ce{D}]\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}[\ce{C}]}{\mathrm{d}t} &= +k_2[\ce{A}][\ce{B}] -k_3[\ce{A}][\ce{C}] +\tfrac{1}{2}k_4[\ce{A}][\ce{D}]\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}[\ce{D}]}{\mathrm{d}t} &= +k_3[\ce{A}][\ce{C}] -k_4[\ce{A}][\ce{D}]\\
\end{align}

Is this wrong-headed? What conceptual issue am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reaction rates should be defined in terms of the [Extent of reaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extent_of_reaction) ($\xi$) that corresponds to the number of moles (or the molarity for reactions in solution) of specie $i$ divided by the the stoichiometric number, $\nu_i$:
$$\xi = \frac{[i]}{\nu_i}$$
Therefore, considering that the first reaction should be:
$$\ce{A + A -> B ~=~ 2A -> B}$$
The corresponding reaction rates are:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}\xi}{\mathrm{d}t} = -\frac{1}{2} \frac{\mathrm{d}[\ce{A}]}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{\mathrm{d}[\ce{B}]}{\mathrm{d}t}$$
In this way, the reaction rate is always the same (positive) number, independently on the specie we are referring to. 
The global rate equations are:
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}[\ce{A}]}{\mathrm{d}t} &= −2k_1[\ce{A}]^2−k_2[\ce{A}][\ce{B}]−k_3[\ce{A}][\ce{C}]−k_4[\ce{A}][\ce{D}]\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}[\ce{B}]}{\mathrm{d}t} &= 2k_1[\ce{A}]^2−k_2[\ce{A}][\ce{B}]+k_4[\ce{A}][D]\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}[\ce{C}]}{\mathrm{d}t} &= k_2[\ce{A}][\ce{B}] -k_3[\ce{A}][\ce{C}] +k_4[\ce{A}][\ce{D}]\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}[\ce{D}]}{\mathrm{d}t} &= k_3[\ce{A}][\ce{C}] -k_4[\ce{A}][\ce{D}]\\
\end{align}

It is conceptually wrong to assume that

> the products of $\ce{A + D}$ should be split evenly between $\ce{B}$ and $\ce{C}$.

The reaction scheme you described is the "parallel reactions" model. The amount of $\ce{A}$ consumed by each reaction depends on the specific rate. The stoichiometry of the first step says that every time 1 molecule of $\ce{B}$ is produced 2 molecules of $\ce{A}$ are consumed. But maybe $k_1$ is very small and so all the other process will consume $\ce{A}$ much more rapidly than this one.

You cannot predict what will happen in a reaction system just looking at the stoichiometry of each step. If you have a large amount of $\ce{C}$, it will probably consume a lot of $\ce{A}$ in the third step, producing a lot of $\ce{D}$ that, in turn, will produce a lot of $\ce{B}$, etc. Stoichiometry is just one piece of information. But kinetics is much more that this.

Comment: Should your third equation read $-\tfrac{1}{2}\tfrac{d[\mathrm{A}]}{dt}$? I can see how this works with one reaction, but A reacts with three other species as well; where does the factor of 1/2 fit in to the full differential equation?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Third equation states that $\frac{d\xi}{dt} corresponds to $\frac 1 \nu_i \frac{d[i]} {dt}$ for every specie $i$.
The full differential equation is just the combination of the expressions for all the reagents in term of $\xi$ so that the stoichiometric number is automatically take into account.
I edited the answer adding the global expressions for each concentration variatiation.

Comment: I have updated your post with some more chemistry markup. If you want to know more, please have a look [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) and [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/4945). Even if it is tempting, please do not use markup in the title field, see [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/149/4945) for details.
You might also want to revisit your comment, that got a little messed up.

Comment: Thank you for the more expansive explanation. What I talked about the third equation, you wrote: $\frac{\mathrm{d}\xi}{\mathrm{d}t} = -\frac{1}{2}\frac{[\ce{A}]}{\mathrm{d}t}$. The right hand side should be a derivative, $-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\mathrm{d}[\ce{A}]}{\mathrm{d}t}$.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. I missed a "d". I edited my answer to correct the problem.